# Why is my 'load' event/function not beeing executed after switching to jQuery 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-3

Since I've upgraded from `jQuery 1.x` / `jQuery 2.x` to `jQuery 3.x`, my existing code will not be executed correctly anymore. Everything works fine, but the `load` event listener gets not triggered anymore or just sometimes:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).on("load", function() {
        // this line will never/occasionally be executed
        console.log("window is loaded!");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem can be occur when using/switching to `jQuery 3`. It's because all `ready states` in the new `jQuery 3` are now fully `asynchron`. This means, that there is no given order for your code to be executed.

Because of this, it could happen, that `load` is been triggered **before** your `ready state` has been executed. When your `ready` function now finally gets triggered, your `load` listener is too late and will not be executed.

---

**jQuery Usage:**

To change this behavior, just remove the `ready state` around your `load` event listener initialization. There is no need to encapsulate this with a `ready` function. You can initialize them without.

```
// $(function() {
    $(window).on("load", function() {
        // this line will now be executed again
        console.log("window is loaded!");
    });
// });
```

If you need or want to register both events, you can register the `load` event by yourself and decide inside the `ready state` what to do next.

```
// track the loading state by yourself
var windowLoaded = false;
$(window).on("load", function() {
    windowLoaded = true;
});

$(function() {
    function afterLoad() {
        console.log("loaded");
    }

    // decide inside your ready state what to do
    if( !windowLoaded ) {
        $(window).on("load", afterLoad);
    }
    else {
        afterLoad();
    }
});
```

---

**jQuery Plugins:**

Another case would be jQuery plugins, that uses the `load` event too. For example:

```
(function($, window) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
        $(window).on("load", start);

        function start() {
            console.log("plugin initialized and window loaded");
        }
    };
})(jQuery, window);
```

If a developer/user now wraps the plugin initialization in a `ready state` the problem could happen again, just like explained before:

```
$(function() {
    $("#element").myPlugin();
});
```

A solution would be to track the `load` event in your plugin on your own, to *break out* the `ready state`.

```
(function($, window) {
    // track the loading state beside the plugin initialization
    var windowLoaded = false;
    $(window).on("load", function() {
        windowLoaded = true;
    });

    $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
        // decide inside your plugin how to start
        if( !windowLoaded ) {
            $(window).on("load", start);
        }
        else {
            start();
        }

        function start() {
            console.log("plugin initialized and window loaded");
        }
    };
})(jQuery, window);
```

---

**Conclusion:**

Even when this problem not happens to you, in your tests, you should change those code immediately, when using `jQuery 3`, because other users/different browser can run into this trouble. Others may got the problem, because it is `asynchron`, you could never know when/if your code gets executed ...

Comment: one does will simply understand even he don't want to!

Comment: Excuse me, I don't understand your comment. Could you please explain what you mean? @CeylanMumunKocabaş

Comment: you explained it good and it is understandable, even if i do not want to understand it - i will, i got me know?

Comment: Are you sure this is a new feature in jq3? Because it is still using the internal ready deferred object. And the behaviour you describe can be replicated in jq1.x - 2.x. So to make it clearer, can you provide a sample working in older jq version that would fail in jq3.0? And have you any link regarding this change in jq3.x? Thank you  EDIT: i see some change, before it was using a promise, now in jq3, it is using deferred object but i'm not sure about any deeper change though

Comment: I really can say it is new. I have a plugin called `Lazy` on GitHub and became many of those problems since jQuery 3 is out, because I use `load` in the initialization. Here is one open issue: https://github.com/eisbehr-/jquery.lazy/issues/55. I even discussed this problem with the jQuery core team, which says that it is a 'real propblem' and new to jQuery 3, because of the changed (even noted in the release notes). You can read about it here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3194. Later I can create an example for this, if still needed ...

Comment: This is definitely good links. Thank you very much, i appreciate!