# Using '$' instead of 'jQuery' in WordPress

Tags: jquery

jQuery included with WordPress is in [compatibility mode](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/). To avoid conflicts with other libraries we can not use the `$` shortcut for `jQuery`. To use the `$` sign we use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#myid').css({'background': 'black', 'color': 'white'});
});
```

This works. But my question is how to do the same with window load. I have been facing this problem since last few projects. So, thought better to make the concept clear.

```
jQuery(window).load(function($) {
    $('#myid').css({'background': 'black', 'color': 'white'});
});
```

With this I get an error that says : `$ is not a function`. So, I'm unable to use `$` inside of the `window.load` code block. Can anyone help how I can use the `$` shortcut inside `window.load`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's called [*no conflict mode*](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/), and not *compatibility mode*. To get this working, you have to use a `closure` or [`IIFE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) then, only `ready states` passes the jQuery object as parameter, `load` and others will not do this.

```
(function($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#myid').css({'background': 'black', 'color': 'white'});
    });
})(jQuery)
```

If your `load` is already inside a `ready state` you can use it directly too (*just as example, you [should not put a `window load` inside a `ready state`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585373/why-is-my-load-event-function-not-beeing-executed-after-switching-to-jquery-3) in general*):

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#myid').css({'background': 'black', 'color': 'white'});
    });
});
```

And note that [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for such task is deprecated! You should use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.