# jQuery init function not working

Tags: jquery

jQuery code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#slider").flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        directionNav: false,
        init: function (slider) {
            // lazy load
            $("img.lazy").slice(0,1).each(function () {
                alert('init running');
                var src = $(this).attr("data-src");
                $(this).attr("src", src).removeAttr("data-src").removeClass("lazy");
            });
        },
        before: function (slider) {
            // lazy load
            $("img.lazy").slice(0,2).each(function () {
                alert('before running');
                var src = $(this).attr("data-src");
                $(this).attr("src", src).removeAttr("data-src").removeClass("lazy");
            });
        },
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        sync: "#carousel",
    })
})
```

JSFIDDLE URL:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/6z5L31tg/
```

init function is not working. even it not alerting me. can you please explain to me why it not working? and How can I resolve this issue? I am weak in English. please apologize me if I made any Grammatical or Spelling mistakes.

Comment: How many `$("img.lazy")` are there on your page?

Comment: Perhaps silly but, do you call it somewhere?

Comment: may be more than 5

Comment: @Roberrrt I am calling it inside jQuery function.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on e.g. jsfiddle or jsbin.

Comment: @secelite wait I will be update code

Comment: @secelite sir I updated but my flexslider is not working injsfiddle

Comment: @secelite sir may I know you checked jsfiddle?

Comment: @ShahRushabh you are using the event `.load()`, which was [replaced by the same named ajax method in jQuery 3.0](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `.load()` event,  which was replaced by the same named ajax method in jQuery 3.0.

From the [upgrade guide](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed):

> The event .load() method conflicted with the ajax .load() method. The
>   .error() method could not be used with window.onerror because of the
>   way the DOM method is defined. If you need to attach events by these
>   names, use the .on() method, e.g. change $("img").load(fn) to
>   $(img).on("load", fn).

I would also advise you to load the slider when the DOM is ready. I updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6z5L31tg/2/

Comment: Correct, now correct way is `$(window).on('load', ...)`. More information to thore ready handlers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585373/why-is-my-load-event-function-not-beeing-executed-after-switching-to-jquery-3