# this code wont run on jquery-3.1.0.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-3

Is there any reason why this code wont run on JS 3.1.0 running locally ( downloaded from http://jquery.com/download/ ) but runs fine when I load it from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
$(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");;
});
</script>
```

I'm confuse... please help...

Comment: why are you using the load event? try a document ready statement `$(function(){})`

Comment: use universal document ready statement.. .

Comment: Did you debug this code?

Comment: See also [Why is my 'load' event/function not beeing executed after switching to jQuery 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585373/why-is-my-load-event-function-not-beeing-executed-after-switching-to-jquery-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery that you're using here http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js uses jQuery **1.6.1**, while the jQuery that you've downloaded from https://jquery.com/download/ uses jQuery **3**.

And in the documentation of jQuery 3 [here](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed), it says:

> Breaking change: .load(), .unload(), and .error() removed

So instead of using `.load()` you can just use `$(function() {});` like this:

```
$(function() {
  // insert code here...
});
```

Comment: Note, `.ready()` was slated for deprecation by jQuery authors, though not sure if or when that would occur.

Comment: Cool, I've updated the answer now to using `$(function() {});` instead of `.ready()` to be sure. Thanks!

Comment: thanks... I was trying to show a loading animation while the pages loaded in the background...

Answer (score 1):

The load() method is removed in Jquery version 3.0.

Check this link for more changes on Jquery version 3.0
https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed